# The truth value of a Series is ambiguous Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

What's the problem with this code? I used many comparison lambda function on the dataframe,but this one returns `ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', u'occurred at index 2')` error.

I searched about it and found many question asked before about it,but none of them fit my problem.

My code:

```
def Return(close,pClose):
    i = ((close - pClose) / close) * 100
    if (i > 0):
        return 1
    if (i < 0):
        return 0

df['return'] = df.apply(lambda y:Return(close=df['Close'], pClose=df['pClose']),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem with your code is that you pass the whole column of the dataframe to your function:

```
df.apply(lambda y:Return(close=df['Close'], pClose=df['pClose']),axis=1)
```

In the function you are calculating a new value i which is in fact a column:

```
i = ((close - pClose) / close) * 100
```

In the comparison statement thencannot decide how to evaluate what you are trying to do because it gets a column as input:

```
if (i > 0):
```

So I think what you want is something like:

```
df['return'] = df.apply(lambda y:Return(close=y['Close'], pClose=y['pClose']),axis=1)
```

Comment: Yes!!! I forgot to add `y` before the `['close']` and `['pClose']` !! I was so shocked by it! I performed many lambda function like this,but this one returns an error! Thank you